# Using single quote in an Exec statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having issues executing a SQL statement from a stored proc having single quotes. Here is my query from a stored procedure that I am executing.

```
EXEC('UPDATE myTABLE 
         SET myCOLUMN = (SELECT Replace('OSINGLEQUOTEJOHN DOE','SINGLEQUOTE','''')')
```

I am trying to update table "myTABLE" column "myCOLUMN" with a value "O'John Doe"

The actual query is like this, i tried to simplify it a bit in the above example

```
EXEC('UPDATE myTABLE 
         SET myCOLUMN = (SELECT Replace('+ @IntegrationGuardian2FullName +','SINGLEQUOTE','''')')
```

The value of `@IntegrationGuardian2FullName` is "OSINGLEQUOTEJOHN DOE". Hope that makes more sense.

Can any body help me formatting this query?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use:

```
EXEC('UPDATE myTABLE 
        SET myCOLUMN = (SELECT REPLACE(''OSINGLEQUOTEJOHN DOE'',
                                       ''SINGLEQUOTE'',
                                       ''''''''))')
```

What you provided needed two single quotes around the string, and what to replace, and additional single quotes because of the single quote escaping necessary for dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 12):

You need to double-escape the single quote inside the quoted string - so use two single quotes to wrap the string, and four (i.e. two escaped quotes) which will be un-escaped into a pair of single quotes when the query is parsed, and then un-escaped *again* into the single quote you actually want to insert:

```
EXEC('UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = ''John''''O Doe''')
```

Answer (score 2):

While OMG Ponies' answer was perfect and helped me as well, something that was not immediately obvious to me is how that worked.
Here is how I understood, and may help OP or anyone else still looking, to apply to any situation.

Using a simple example 
`sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'LName','Uname'`

Transformed
 `select (' sp_change_users_login ''update_one '', ''LName '' ,''Uname '' ')`

All that has been done is, [as OMG Ponies said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364347/3552195), wrap the entire statement in single quotes(*'* ).
Then, for every single quote that is already present('), place one more to precede it(*'* ).
I am not able to bold the single quotes that were added in the second statement, to make it clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UPDATE myTABLE SET myCOLUMN='O''John Doe'

 EXEC('UPDATE myTABLE SET myCOLUMN=''O''John Doe''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use the `CHAR()` function.

```sql
EXEC('SELECT ''O'' + CHAR(39) + ''JOHN DOE'' as [Name]');
```

```sql
EXEC('SELECT CHAR(39) as SingleQuote, CHAR(34) as DoubleQuote;')
```